# Active directory is not working on VM - Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtual-machines, virtualbox

I am new to virtual machines. 
Just installed Oracle  virtualbox and trying to run the virtual machine from `.vhd` file.
VM is running fine but my Active Directory is not Operational. Some times it gives me the error saying `Server is not operational.`

!For details please see the screenshot.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BQBU.jpg)

Thanks in advance

Updated:

```
VirtualBox (XP)COM Server 4.1.8 r75467 win.amd64 (Dec 19 2011 13:40:38) release log
00:00:00.000 main     Log opened 2012-02-16T13:08:09.599027000Z
00:00:00.000 main     OS Product: Windows 7
00:00:00.000 main     OS Release: 6.1.7601
00:00:00.000 main     Executable: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxSVC.exe
00:00:00.000 main     Process ID: 6484
00:00:00.000 main     Package type: WINDOWS_64BITS_GENERIC
00:00:00.078          Loading settings file     
"C:\Users\P10141538/.VirtualBox\VirtualBox.xml" with version "1.12-windows"
00:00:00.094          usbLibDevCfgDrGet: DeviceIoControl 1 fail winEr (31)
00:00:00.296          VDInit finished
00:00:00.312          Loading settings file "C:\Users\P10141538\VirtualBox    
VMs\CRM2011DevVM\CRM2011DevVM.vbox" with version "1.12-windows"
00:00:09.610 Medium::Task ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004) aIID= 
{53f9cc0c-e0fd-40a5-a404-a7a5272082cd} aComponent={Medium} aText={Could not delete the 
medium storage unit 'C:\VMs\CRM 2011 backup 07 Feb 12.vhd'.
00:00:09.610 Medium::Task VD: error VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND opening image file 'C:\VMs\CRM 
2011 backup 07 Feb 12.vhd' (VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)}, preserve=false
00:00:09.610 MachineDelete ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004) aIID=
{5eaa9319-62fc-4b0a-843c-0cb1940f8a91} aComponent={Machine} aText={Could not delete the 
medium storage unit 'C:\VMs\CRM 2011 backup 07 Feb 12.vhd'.
00:00:09.610 MachineDelete VD: error VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND opening image file 'C:\VMs\CRM 
2011 backup 07 Feb 12.vhd' (VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)}, preserve=false
00:00:52.011          ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004) aIID={5eaa9319-
62fc-4b0a-843c-0cb1940f8a91} aComponent={Machine} aText={Machine settings file 
'C:\Users\P10141538\VirtualBox VMs\CRM2011DevVM\CRM2011DevVM.vbox' already exists}, 
preserve=false

00:01:45.394          ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_INVALID_VM_STATE (0x80bb0002) aIID=
{5eaa9319-62fc-4b0a-843c-0cb1940f8a91} aComponent={Machine} aText={Machine is not locked     
for session (session state: Unlocked)}, preserve=false
00:01:45.737          ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80bb0005) aIID={5eaa9319-
62fc-4b0a-843c-0cb1940f8a91} aComponent={SessionMachine} aText={Saved screenshot data is 
not available (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED)}, preserve=false

00:12:00.491 USBPROXY usbLibDevCfgDrGet: DeviceIoControl 1 fail winEr (31)
00:12:02.175 USBPROXY usbLibDevCfgDrGet: DeviceIoControl 1 fail winEr (31)
00:12:02.893 USBPROXY usbLibDevCfgDrGet: DeviceIoControl 1 fail winEr (31)
00:12:04.281 USBPROXY usbLibDevCfgDrGet: DeviceIoControl 1 fail winEr (31)
```

Comment: What does it say in your logs? Are you bridging the VM? ...why are you running an AD server in VirtualBox and not in a dedicated VM host, like VMWare ESXi or Hyper-V?

Comment: hi @BartSilverstrim in Log it says `Server is not operational.` Its my company's recommendation to use VirtualBox to run VM, I am quite new to in so I don't even know much about  VMWare ESXi and Hyper-V. AD is not allowing me to run CRM on VM. Thanks

Comment: Are all needed services running? Is this the only domain controller?  Is this a newly created VM?

Comment: Duplicate SuperUser http://superuser.com/questions/390681/active-directory-is-not-working-on-vm-windows-server-2008

Comment: Hi @DaveM, yes all services are running. Actually my Machine is not but I have copied `.vhd` from someone else's machine. which is working fine for him.

Comment: @DaveM I have deleted the duplicate from SuperUser.

Comment: ...you're running two AD servers on machines that think they're identical at the same time on the same network? This could cause problems...

Comment: We can pretty much guarantee that if you copy a VHD for a domain controller and try to start it up that you will have issues. I hope this is a test environment and not in production.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to create a new VM instead of copying one from someone else. Copying a VM and putting it on the same network, especially if it is a domain controller, will cause issues.

Start from scratch with this one, and be sure that you understand how the VirtualBox VM is working. Once you have that in place, you can then begin learning how to build a member server and promote it to a domain controller for Active Directory. As stated above, I would recommend that you first do this in a test environment before attempting this in a live production environment.

Comment: Do you already have an Active Directory domain set up in the test environment, or would this be your first domain controller?